# Can this rxjs merge logic be simplified?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, rxjs, observable

I have an observable (onAuthStateChanged) from the Firebase client that:

1. emits `null` immediately if the user is *not* signed in, and
2. emits `null` and then a `user object` a few moments later if the user *is* signed in.

```js
const observable = new Observable((obs) => {
    return app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(
        obs.next,
        obs.error,
        obs.complete
    )
})
```

What I want is to:

1. ignore any emitted `null` values for the first 1000ms of the app lifecycle (`null` coming after 1000ms is accepted)
2. always emit `user object` regardless of what time it comes
3. if no `user object` comes in the first 1000ms, then emit `null` at the 1000ms mark

Here is what I've done (and it seems to work). However, I'm reluctant to use this code as it  doesn't seem that concise:

```js
const o1 = observable.pipe(skipUntil(timer(1000)))

const o2 = observable.pipe(
    takeUntil(o1),
    filter((user) => user !== null)
)

const o3 = timer(1000).pipe(takeUntil(o2), mapTo(null))

merge(o1, o2, o3).subscribe({
    next: setUser,
    error: console.log,
    complete: () => console.log("error: obs completed, this shouldn't happen"),
})
```

Is there a way to do this without merge? I tried going through the docs but I'm quite lost.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just little thing, I think you could change the `mapTo` in the o3 to `defaultIfEmpty` instead. Anyway I think this is simple, changing this to one with multiple super “intelligent” pipes will just complicate things and make it harder for the reader to understand…

Comment: @RazLuvaton I tried fitting in defaultIfEmpty but I can't seem to get the desired solution out of it. Thanks for the reassurances, will stick with this logic for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`concat`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat) instead of merge.  Think of it as using the first source until it completes, then use the second source.

```js
const nonNullUser = firebaseUser.pipe(
    filter(user => user !== null),
    takeUntil(timer(1000))
);

const user = concat(nonNullUser, firebaseUser);

user.subscribe(...);
```

---

I just realized that this solution will not explicitly perform step #3 "*emit null at the 1000ms mark*".  I was thinking subscribing to `firebaseUser` would emit the latest value. But, I'm not sure if that's true for your scenario.

If not, we could easily achieve this by adding [`shareReplay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay) like this:

```js
const firebaseUser = observable.pipe(shareReplay(1));
```

Comment: I took a look at concat but I don't think it works here. It would mean that o2 cannot start until o3 completes (which happens after a delay of 1s). Further, we want o1 to be the observable that survives as time goes to infinity (it's the one that would detect sign-ins and sign-outs well into the future)

Comment: Hold on a moment... I think you are on to something. Your solution does work _except_ it doesn't meet requirement no. 3 if no user object comes in the first 1000ms, then emit null at the 1000ms mark

Comment: In my mental model, there are only 2 possible "sources". #1 is the non-null source, which is used for the first 1000ms. Then #2, the long lived source (*without filtering out null values*), from firebase.  It's true that source #2 can't be used until #1 completes, however, they are really the same source under the hood, essentially, the only difference is that the null filtering logic is removed.

Comment: LOL - I just noticed that. answer updated  about adding in [`shareReplay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay)

Comment: It's true that we could replay the `null` that we know was there, but to me the solution I've laid out specifically yields a `null`, which seems somewhat clearer in intent. Also, I'm not sure how to compose this because we only want to replay the `null` if and only if there was no `user` emitted. In your mental model, it would be something like: concat(nonNullUser, IFF(!user,yeild null, otherwise do nothing) ,firebaseUser)

Comment: Bobby, there is an [`iif`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/conditional/iif) operator

Comment: Secondly, I agree with Bobby which is clearer by specifying explicitly. If you want to use the `shareReplay` I suggest you write a comment explaining that it cover scenario no. 3 + why it does (how shareReplay help in covering that scenario)

Comment: Fair point.  I think I initially made an assumption that the most recent value would be received upon subscription to the firebase auth (*this is the behavior is the AngularFire package, and many others where the package is the source of truth of some type of state*).   Since that isn't the case here, I see how it could seem a little hacky to add a shareReplay into the mix.

Answer (score 1):

While I liked the answer from @BizzyBob I was genuinely intrigued by these requirements that I wanted to see what other options were available. Here's what I produced:

```
const auth$ = observable.pipe(
    startWith(null)
)

const null$ = timer(1000).pipe(
    switchMap(_=>auth$)
)

const valid$ = auth$.pipe(
    filter(user=>!!user)
)

const user$ = race(null$, valid$);
```

We have our source `auth$` observable which gets your Firebase data. However, `startWith()` will immediately emit `null` before any values coming from Firebase.

I declared two observables for null and non-null cases, `null$` and `valid$`.

The `null$` observable will subscribe to `auth$` after 1000ms. When this happens it immediately emits `null` thanks to the `startWith()` operator.

The `valid$` observable subscribes to `auth$` immediately but only emits valid user data thanks to `filter()`. It won't emit `startWith(null)` because it is caught by the filter.

Last, we declare `user$` by using the `race()` operator. This operator accepts a list of observables as its parameters. The first observable to emit a value wins and is the resulting subscription.

So in our race, `valid$` has 1000ms to emit a valid user. If it doesn't, `race()` will subscribe to `null$` resulting in the immediate `null`, and all future values coming from Firebase.

Comment: I just tested it and... it works, except for one small issue: it emits a double-`null` if the user isn't signed in at the 1 second mark. However, I'll accept the answer because the double-`null` is innocuous.

Mind explaining the magic behind this? :D

Comment: I updated my answer to include an explanation. And sorry about the double `null` emits. I added the `startWith(null)` to guarantee `null` emits after 1000ms. If you want to avoid duplicate `null` emits, you can add `distinctUntilChanged()` at the end of the pipe inside `auth$`.

Comment: One issue I'm seeing is if the user signs out; the resulting `null` would get filtered. This could be worked around by some additional logic in the button handler or if we could somehow remove the filter after 1s